# In R: Extract specific columns from data frame by date and keep basic columns at beginning

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have several big data frames with time series data for specific coordinates from 2007-2019. 8113 rows and 301 columns. Each year is divided in 16 days time steps, which results in 23 values per year per coordinate.
It looks like this:

```
X   longitude   latitude   label     2007-01-07   2007-01-23 ... 2019-12-10   2019-12-26  
1   -56.58652   -30.87850  cropland  0.08367160   0.07883158     0.07414120   0.08120061
2   -56.58458   -30.88260  cropland  0.07888613   0.07438400     0.07831833   0.07352642
3   -56.58429   -30.87860  cropland  0.08331446   0.07837244     0.07169452   0.07229450
```

I would like to subset the data frame into years, keeping the first four columns the same for each subset. Then afterwards save them all together in a list of dataframes. So the output I am looking for should be like this:

```
X   longitude   latitude   label     2007-01-07   2007-01-23   ...
1   -56.58652   -30.87850  cropland  0.08367160   0.07883158   ...  
2   -56.58458   -30.88260  cropland  0.07888613   0.07438400   ...  
3   -56.58429   -30.87860  cropland  0.08331446   0.07837244   ...
```

```
X   longitude   latitude   label     2008-01-10   2008-01-26   ...
1   -56.58652   -30.87850  cropland  0.08367160   0.07883158   ...  
2   -56.58458   -30.88260  cropland  0.07888613   0.07438400   ...  
3   -56.58429   -30.87860  cropland  0.08331446   0.07837244   ...
```

...

```
X   longitude   latitude   label     2019-01-12   2019-01-28   ...
1   -56.58652   -30.87850  cropland  0.08367160   0.07883158   ...  
2   -56.58458   -30.88260  cropland  0.07888613   0.07438400   ...  
3   -56.58429   -30.87860  cropland  0.08331446   0.07837244   ...
```

I need to do that for 8 dataframes like the example above.
I know, this should be quite basic, but I'm also quite new to R and programming in general. So I'm thankful for any hint on that one!
Cheers!

Comment: It would help to see exactly what your column names are (looks like dates, starting with numbers - no letters, is that correct?) Could you edit your question and use `dput(df[1:10, 1:10])` and provide actual data on first 10 rows and columns to reproduce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split.default` to split data based on year and with `lapply` `cbind` the first four columns to each list.

```
result <- lapply(split.default(df[-(1:4)], 
                 format(as.Date(names(df)[-(1:4)], 'X%Y.%m.%d'), '%Y')), 
                 function(x) cbind(df[1:4], x))
```

R tries to discourage column names starting with numbers so if you read the data with default options it will change column name from `2007-01-07` to `X2007.01.07` so keeping that in mind I have used `'X%Y.%m.%d'` in `as.Date`. If you have somehow managed to read column names as you have shown i.e `2007-01-07` use `%Y-%m-%d` in `as.Date`.